# chrome.experimental.discovery.suggest not suggesting to chrome://newtab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried to suggest `http://www.w3schools.com` to `chrome://newtab`, neither i have success nor errors through [discovery](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.discovery.html#type-SuggestDetails).

After a cursory look at [source code](https://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/discovery/discovery_api.cc) i have tried the same code in different profiles, but no worth.

```
  registry->Add(extension_id(), suggested_link.Pass());
```

is not adding my link to `chrome://newtab`.

**Trivial Demonstration**

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Discovery Demo",
"description":"This demonstrates Discovery API",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1",
"permissions":["experimental"],
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"screen.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
}
}
```

***popup.html***

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***popup.js***

```
chrome.experimental.discovery.suggest({
    "urlImage": chrome.extension.getURL("screen.png"),
    "score": 1.0,
    "linkUrl": "http://www.w3schools.com",
    "linkText": "Sample"
});
```

Is there any thing i missed out, any suggestions?

Comment: The feature requires the `--enable-suggestions-ntp` flag (visit `chrome://flags` and search for ntp and discovery). Still, after enabling this flag, I can't get the API to work. It could be broken.

Comment: @RobW Exactly i enabled the flags, but can't get it to work